# What are best practices to compute an audio spectrogram?

Tags: fft, audio, python, spectrogram

The spectrogram if generally defined with the squared magnitude of the fft. However, in lots of implementation, it seems that people just use the magnitude without square.

Moreover an audio signal is by convention scale between -1 and 1. This scaling often needs a supplementary step in implementations, in python language for example, which is not always do.

Finally, what are best practices to compute an audio spectrogram?
- square magnitude of the fft / magnitude of the fft ?
- Integer audio values / scaling (-1 to 1) audio values

**EDIT**

As the comments tell, these are questions without consequences if the aim is to plot an image of the spectrogram.

However, I would like to use the matrix of the spectrogram as an entry point for sound analysis and recognition. In this case, the computation process matters and I find curious that the implementations differ so often.

Comment: Aren't all those issues mute, given the next step is a commonly a fairly arbitrary color mapping?

Comment: @hotpaw2 Indeed, when the final goal is to plot an image, this questions can be useless. However, I want to do some process on the matrix of the spectrogram. In this case, it matters.

Comment: The best practices to display a nice or informative looking spectrogram (the most common use) are likely not the same as needed for doing some other processing on the data.  So you will need to specify the needs of your desired processing to get a useful answer.

Comment: In most cases the best practice is to use a logarithmic scale such as decibels (dB). In this case there is no difference between magnitude and magnitude squared. The absolute scaling is just an offset and the best choice depends on the specific application

Comment: Mute and moot are different.  These issues are moot - irrelevant.  Mute means they can't speak, which is true but moot. :)

Comment: Scaling the signal to the range 1,-1 means that you don't have any idea of the absolute level of the signal.  Yo can only work with relative values - say, the FFt shows that the 100Hz magnitude is 20dB below the 1kHz magnitude.  If you leave the levels as sampled, and know the conditions they were sampled under, then you could (with the correct math) be able to say that the 100Hz magnitude is -70dBm (for example) which tells you how much power that magnitude really represents.

Answer (score 1):

I think, perhaps, that the statement should be reversed: that a lot of implementations "just" use the square magnitude. This is because the DFT of a real-valued signal is typically complex, so that the square magnitude is just the product of complex conjugates, e.g.:

> X<sup>*</sup>(f) · X(f)

This requires less computation than the magnitude, which would follow the same algorithm, but with a subsequent square-root.

The square magnitude of a DFT is formally known as the `Power Spectrum`.